# Can you use Layer-wise relevance propagation(LRP) for Object Detection?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I want to use the LRP to evaluate an image for explainability. I have 1 file tensorflow graph .pb.
I am wondering if I can use LRP for object detection and Tensorflow?
Anyone with suggestions is encouraged

Comment: Is this a purely theoretical question, or are you trying to do this and running into problems with the implementation? The latter is on-topic here, provided you post the code and explain the problem. The former is not - you might try your luck over at [stats.SE] instead, but will probably have to provide more context than you have done so far.

Comment: Thanks for answering. i am newbie and i am wanting to explain the model with LRP. Where my model is RCNN type model, Fast RCNN is saved as Tensorflow Graph. I just need an idea or a toolbox to implement them.